# Stubbing out class method using Mocha

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

I have a method I want to test using rspec and Mocha. My aim is to stub out `Dir.glob` in order to just return a simple array of one file. The method is defined as so:

```
def my_method
  Dir.glob("#{upload_dir}/*.pdf").each do |file|
    ...
  end
end
```

And the test:

```
it "ignores a file of no size" do
  zero_file = File.expand_path("../fixtures/zero_size_file_12345.pdf", __FILE__)
  Dir.expects(:glob).returns([zero_file])

  ...
end
```

The problem is that the method `upload_dir` is not something I want to test here, and I assumed if I stubbed out any call to `Dir.glob` then `upload_dir` would never be called. If I put a debugger in before the call to `Dir.glob` and call `Dir.glob`, then I see my array of one zero file, so the stubbing is definitely working. However, when the test actually calls the method `Dir.glob("#{upload_dir}/*.pdf")`, it's trying to then call `upload_dir`.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, rspec 2.12.0 and mocha 0.13.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its calling upload_dir because it has to to build the string to pass to glob.  You could stub it by adding something like -

[YourClass].expects(:upload_dir).returns("foo")

and then expect that your code passes "foo/*.pdf" to glob.

Answer (score 4):

What @Scott suggests would probably work. So +1 for his answer.

However, you should think about extracting out the line:

```
Dir.glob("#{upload_dir}/*.pdf")
```

into a method that clarifies intent,for e.g. `pdf_files_to_upload`.

You could then stub out that method on the object under test to return an array as required. You are then decoupled from the upload_dir method entirely and don't need to care how the list of PDF files is generated. A more declarative `my_method` would result!

HTH.